# Where can I get WebShere Application Server v7 plugin for eclipse (3.7.1 Indigo)?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, websphere-7

If you are aware of such plugin, I'd appreciate sharing with me a download link (or any relevant info)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to get it via Help > Marketplace.